# Pycronofy timezone id not being set correctly

Tags: python-3.x, cronofy

Trying to integrate [Cronofy](https://www.cronofy.com/developers/tutorials/getting-started/#reading-calendar-events) to an app using the Python package [pycronofy](https://github.com/cronofy/pycronofy).

But cant seem to get the results back in the right timezone even after setting it as required.

```
events = cronofy.read_events(calendar_ids=('CAL_ID',),from_date=from_date, to_date=to_date, tzid='Asia/Kolkata')

print (events.json())
```

The returning json is always in the UTC timezone. This library doesnt seem to have an SO tag but hoping that someone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tzid` parameter relates to the restriction of events for the request, to get richer time information in the response you need to request `localized_times`:

```
events = cronofy.read_events(calendar_ids=('CAL_ID',),
                             from_date=from_date,
                             to_date=to_date,
                             tzid='Asia/Kolkata',
                             localized_times=True)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Didnt see that parameter in the README. Perhaps I should add it.